# lubuntu does not see executable file generated by ocamlopt on NixOS

Tags: ocaml, x86-64, executable, nixos

i created executable "**standalone**" file in NixOS (x86_64) using "**ocamlopt**" native compiler with option -linkall.  and the generated program is executed in NixOS. so far so good

after that i tried to execute this file under Lubuntu

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~/Documents$ uname -a
Linux lubuntu 4.18.0-10-generic #11-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 11 15:13:55 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

but recieved:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~/Documents$ ./a.out 
bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

i am quite sure that architecture is suitable:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~/Documents$ objdump -h a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

what i did wrong? on NixOS, on OCaml, on Lubuntu?

Tnx in advance

UDP:  my NixOS distro:

```
$> uname -a
Linux cat 4.19.36 #1-NixOS SMP Sat Apr 20 07:16:05 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ocaml:

```
$> ocamlopt -v                                                                                         
The OCaml native-code compiler, version 4.06.1
```

UDP2:

```
$> readelf -a a.out | grep ld-
      [Requesting program interpreter: /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No such file or directory" (`ENOENT`) when trying to execute a file that does exist usually means that its dynamic linker path (ELF interpreter) doesn't exist.  It's exactly the same error for the same reason you'd get from executing a text file that started with `#!/non-existant/path`

Use `strace ./a.out` to see that the only system call is the `execve` which fails.

Most GNU/Linux distros use `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.  For example `file /bin/ls` on my Arch GNU/Linux desktop shows:

> /bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
>   dynamically linked, **interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2**,
>   BuildID[sha1]=4fef2dc9762eb7d4593f402a65cc02bb3d4c48de, for GNU/Linux
>   3.2.0, stripped

Presumably NixOS, or at least `ocamlopt` on NixOS, uses a different path.  Use `file` to check.  (Or `readelf -a` to show the ELF program headers will also dump the interpreter path.)

`ldd` can also show the interpreter path, but IIRC fails if the path isn't valid.

Comment: @Ston17: well there you go, you just confirmed that this is the answer.  Ubuntu doesn't have a `/nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.  You could create it as a symlink if you wanted.

Comment: @Ston17: Can you build it on Ubuntu and run it on NixOS?  I'd guess that an obscure distro would probably be able to run standard binaries.  As for building on NixOS, I have no idea, I've never heard of it.  You could set up your Ubuntu system with a symlink like `ln -s /   /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27` so it could run NixOS binaries.

Comment: i got it but this is unrealistic way. and i cannot create anything on the target system - let us suppose that this computer is not mine. can i force ocamlopt compiler to link systemlib statically? tnx

Comment: if i will place ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 into the folder with my a.out executable - would it help? tnx

Comment: @Ston17: I have no idea if / how you can create an executable with normal paths using NixOS.  I don't know anything about OCaml either.  You could ask that as a new question; make sure to tag it [tag:nixos].